# Using Docker Compose to connect separate Postgres and Node containers together

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use Docker Compose to connect a Node.js container to a Postgres container. I can run the Node server fine, and can also connect to the Postgres container fine from my local as I've mapped the ports, but I'm unable to get the Node container to connect to the database.

Here's the compose YAML file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api_dev:
    build: ./api
    command: sh -c "sleep 5; npm run dev" # I added the sleep in to wait for the DB to load but it doesn't work either way with or without this sleep part
    container_name: pc-api-dev
    depends_on:
      - dba
    links:
      - dba
    ports:
      - 8001:3001
    volumes:
      - ./api:/home/app/api
      - /home/app/api/node_modules
    working_dir: /home/app/api
    restart: on-failure
  dba:
    container_name: dba
    image: postgres
    expose: 
      - 5432
    ports:
      - '5431:5432'
    env_file:
      - ./api/db.env
```

In my Node container, I'm waiting for the Node server to spin up and attempting to connect to the database in the other container like so:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), async () => {
    console.log('App running...');

    const client = new Client({
        user: 'db-user',
        host: 'dba', // host is set to the service name of the DB in the compose file
        database: 'db-name',
        password: 'db-pass',
        port: 5431,
    })

    try {
        await client.connect()
        console.log(client) // x - can't see this
        client.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
            console.log(err, res) // x - can't see this
            client.end()
        })
        console.log('test') // x - can't see this
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e) // x - also can't see this
    }

});
```

After reading up on it today in depth, I've seen the DB host in the connection code above can't be localhost as that refers to the container which is currently running, so it must be set to the service name of the container we're connecting to (dba in this case). I've also mapped the ports, and can see the DB is ready accepting connections well before my Node server starts.

However, not only can I not connect to the database from Node, I'm also unable to see any success or error console logs from the try catch. It's as if the connection is not resolving, and doesn't ever time out, but I'm not sure.

I've also seen that the "listen_addresses" needs to be updated so other containers can connect to the Postgres container, but struggling to find out how to do this and test when I can't debug the actual issue due to lack of logs.

Any direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to use the standard PostgreSQL port 5432; inter-container connections ignore `ports:`.  `expose:` and `links:` aren't necessary.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice, I’ve changed to using this he 5432 port but still having the same problem. It’s strange because it’s not throwing an error and just hanging.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the container name and can reference that container by it. For example,

```
db:
container_name: container_db
```

And **host:port**

```
DB_URL: container_db:5432
```

Comment: You can also use the Compose service name `db` as a host name.  Compose can pick its own `container_name` and you don't usually need to set this.

Comment: Hey guys thanks. I’ve tried this also but still nothing. I’ve tried exec in to the api_dev service which is attempting to connect to the Postgres container and I can successfully ping the Postgres container which is good. The 5432 port on Postgres is open too. I’ve tried to make a connection on both the pg package and also on Sequelize, and they both hang when connecting. No error message In the catch or success message either. I’m starting to think it’s a problem with the server trying to make the connection rather than the Postgres container but not sure how to confirm it.

Comment: Also if I run the 2 services outside of Docker and update the connection details to localhost so they run from my host machine, they connect perfectly. Tried that to rule out a problem with the code.